# Как отключить cookies и javascript в PhantomJS webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Делаю браузерного бота, хотелось бы узнать как и возможно ли отключить javascript с куками в фантоме посредством C#? Используя язык javascript, справиться с данной задачей не составляет особого труда (об этом гласит инструкция на сайте производителя), но я с ним незнаком. Ещё было бы не плохо узнать как настроить прокси с помощью того же C#, в общем моя цель — максимальная анонимизация приложения.

Comment: А если не секрет, что этот бот будет делать? Ведь если вы отключите JS и захотите накручивать сайту посещаемость, то у вас ничего не выйдет. гугл и яндекс именно через него и заносят данные в свои базы, а включив JS вам прокси не поможет, т.к. вас сразу же идентифицируют и сайт который вы будите посещать этим ботом забанят.

Comment: Бот не для накрутки посещаемости, спасибо за полезную информацию.